# linux c++ libev official example show redundant console behavior

Tags: c++, linux, input, console, libev

I just tried the official example of libev, like below. After compiling and running, I see once I input anything from stdin, the event is triggered, no problem. But what I inputed is still treated as solid input and then appear on my console. My question is: is there a way to avoid this console input from being prompted to console, and just like libev to catch and store it?

Any way in libev can do this?

I paste the official example here:

```
    // a single header file is required
    #include <ev.h>

    #include <stdio.h> // for puts

    // every watcher type has its own typedef'd struct
    // with the name ev_TYPE
    ev_io stdin_watcher;
    ev_timer timeout_watcher;

    // all watcher callbacks have a similar signature
    // this callback is called when data is readable on stdin
    static void
    stdin_cb (EV_P_ ev_io *w, int revents)
    {
      puts ("stdin ready");
      // for one-shot events, one must manually stop the watcher
      // with its corresponding stop function.
      ev_io_stop (EV_A_ w);

      // this causes all nested ev_run's to stop iterating
      ev_break (EV_A_ EVBREAK_ALL);
    }

    // another callback, this time for a time-out
    static void
    timeout_cb (EV_P_ ev_timer *w, int revents)
    {
      puts ("timeout");
      // this causes the innermost ev_run to stop iterating
      ev_break (EV_A_ EVBREAK_ONE);
    }

    int
    main (void)
    {
      // use the default event loop unless you have special needs
      struct ev_loop *loop = EV_DEFAULT;

      // initialise an io watcher, then start it
      // this one will watch for stdin to become readable
      ev_io_init (&stdin_watcher, stdin_cb, /*STDIN_FILENO*/ 0, EV_READ);
      ev_io_start (loop, &stdin_watcher);

      // initialise a timer watcher, then start it
      // simple non-repeating 5.5 second timeout
      ev_timer_init (&timeout_watcher, timeout_cb, 5.5, 0.);
      ev_timer_start (loop, &timeout_watcher);

      // now wait for events to arrive
      ev_run (loop, 0);

      // break was called, so exit
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to disable console echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the echoing of what you write? It's the default behavior of terminal program. You can use [`termios`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) functions and flags to disable echoing. Remember to enable it before exiting your program though.

Answer (score 1):

In `ev_io_init` you are setting what your trigger will be. Instead of setting STDIN_FILENO you can choose to use a fd from a socket for example. Don't know if this is what you are looking for. Here you have an [example](https://git.daplie.com/coolaj86/libev-examples/blob/master/ipc/unix-socket-ipc-daemon.c) of what I am saying.